# Criteria and caching in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine entity called Site with the following field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SiteAsset", mappedBy="site")
 */
protected $assets;
```

I also have a function for getting an element of `$assets` with a given value of its `url` field:

```
public function getAssetByUrl($url) {
    $c = Criteria::create()->
    where(Criteria::expr()->eq('url',$url));
    $matching = $this->assets->matching($c);
    return $matching[0];
}
```

This function behaves very strangely. It appears to work if I run it immediately after fetching the entity from the database. But after a few database operations have been queued up, it begins to fail. I know it is failing, as I can find the asset I want as follows:

```
public function getAssetByUrl($url) {
    foreach($this->assets as $asset) {
        if($asset->getUrl() === $url) {
            return $asset;
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if I combine the two functions into:

```
public function getAssetByUrl($url) {
    foreach($this->assets as $asset) {
        if($asset->getUrl() === $url) {
            error_log('found');
        }
    }

    $c = Criteria::create()->
    where(Criteria::expr()->eq('url',$url));
    $matching = $this->assets->matching($c);
    error_log($matching[0] ? 'found' : 'not found');
    return $matching[0];
}
```

Then the Criteria always fails to find a match (i.e., when the function is called it always prints out 'found' followed by 'not found'). This would suggest that Doctrine is failing to find the entity I want in the case when it has already cached the entities in memory.

How can I ensure that matches are always found, while still making use of Doctrine's Criteria filtering system?

Comment: I recommend that you print with the function `var_dump` the contents of variables: `$url` and `$asset->getUrl()`, in each cycle, so you can see well the result you are sending.

Comment: That was the first step of my debugging. The correct value is being passed through, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the following line:

```
return $matching[0];
```

This returns the right answer if the `PersistentCollection` has not yet been fully fetched from the database. This is because the criteria is converted to an SQL query that returns an array containing only matching items; therefore getting the item at index `0` succeeds.

This returns the wrong answer if the `PersistentCollection` has already been fully fetched. This is because, internally, doctrine calls `array_filter` on the in-memory collection and returns the result. This means that the first element in the result is not necessarily at index `0`, as `array_filter` preserves keys.

The solution was to wrap `$matching` in `array_values($matching)`.